how to use "contains" to Check whether a collection has a date in json .Return true when item is found or return false when not found in power automte
if(
contains(items('Apply_to_each'), 'startDate'),
substring(items('Apply_to_each')['startDate'],0,10),
null
)
this is not working for me
i have tried changing the formula couple of times using contains and without containes like below but dint work
if(empty(items('Apply_to_each')?['startDate']), null, substring(items('Apply_to_each')?['startDate'],0,10))

I would check the output of that JSON and see how is that date formatted. Probably some yyyy.MM.dd, based on your localization. With this information, I would use the contains function with a string which will appear in (and only in) that date.
